# error while filtering the date from data frame

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a big data frame with multiple date columns and i am trying filter date with todays date in date column but unable to filter as i was getting some error below.

Caused by error in `as.POSIXlt.character()`:
! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

below is the date format and class of the column is showing as character

[image]

```
dd <- data.frame(c1 =c("1/16/2023 1:26", "1/16/2023 1:26", "1/16/2023 1:40", "1/16/2023 2:05", 
                       "1/16/2023 2:05", "1/16/2023 2:10"))

dd %>% filter(as.date(c1) == lubridate::today())
dd %>% filter(as.date(as.character(c1) == lubridate::today()))
dd %>% filter(c1 == lubridate::today())
```

Comment: Convert c1 column into a date, then compare with today. At the moment it is a character column, make it a date.

Comment: tried that approach too but still not working

Comment: "not working" is not helpful, show us the output, error, warning.

Comment: Caused by error in as.POSIXlt.character(): ! character string is not in a standard unambiguous mentioned this

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

dd <-
  tibble(
    c1 = c(
      "1/16/2023 1:26",
      "1/16/2023 1:26",
      "1/16/2023 1:40",
      "1/16/2023 2:05",
      "1/16/2023 2:05",
      "1/16/2023 2:10", 
      "5/25/2023 2:10"
    )
  ) 

dd %>%  
  mutate(across(c1, mdy_hm)) %>% 
  filter(date(c1) == today())

# A tibble: 1 x 1
  c1                 
  <dttm>             
1 2023-05-25 02:10:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a format:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dd <- data.frame(c1 =c("1/16/2023 1:26", "1/16/2023 1:26", "1/16/2023 1:40", "1/16/2023 2:05", 
                       "1/16/2023 2:05", "1/16/2023 2:10"))

dd %>% filter(as.Date(c1, format = "%m/%d/%Y") == as.Date("2023-01-16"))
#>               c1
#> 1 1/16/2023 1:26
#> 2 1/16/2023 1:26
#> 3 1/16/2023 1:40
#> 4 1/16/2023 2:05
#> 5 1/16/2023 2:05
#> 6 1/16/2023 2:10
dd %>% filter(as.Date(c1, format = "%m/%d/%y") == lubridate::today())
#> [1] c1
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

btw `as.date()` doesn't exist, try to make your reproducible examples reproducible.